# Another PHP NGINX error: "No input file specified"

Tags: centos, php, nginx, fastcgi

I looked through about 5 questions and blog posts already and tried everything they told me without luck. I can browse to www.example.com/phpinfo.php, but not www.example.com/index.php. I even went so far as to make phpinfo.php a symlink of index.php and phpinfo.php still works while index.php does not.

## Nginx Config

```
[admin@web01 www]$ cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf 
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    # Document root
    index  index.php;
    root   /var/www/sites/example.com/www;

    # Pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~* \.php$ {
        include       fastcgi.conf;
        try_files     $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}

[admin@web01 www]$ cat /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

## Permissions

```
[admin@web01 www]$ ls -al /var/www/sites/example.com/www/*.php
-rw-rw-r--. 1 admin admin 17 Jan 24 10:37 /var/www/sites/example.com/www/index.php
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 admin admin  9 Jan 24 10:37 /var/www/sites/example.com/www/phpinfo.php -> index.php

[admin@web01 www]$ ls -alZ /var/www/sites/example.com/www/*.php
-rw-rw-r--. admin admin unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/sites/example.com/www/index.php
lrwxrwxrwx. admin admin unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/sites/example.com/www/phpinfo.php -> index.php

[admin@web01 ~]# ls -al /var
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root root  4096 Dec 15 18:02 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 23 root root  4096 Dec 15 17:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root  4096 Dec 15 18:13 www

[admin@web01 ~]# ls -al /var/www
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root  root  4096 Dec 15 18:13 .
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root  root  4096 Dec 15 18:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  7 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:35 sites

[admin@web01 ~]# ls -al /var/www/sites
drwxr-xr-x. 7 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root  root  4096 Dec 15 18:13 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 4 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 example.com

[admin@web01 ~]# ls -al /var/www/sites/example.com
drwxrwxr-x.  4 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 .
drwxr-xr-x.  7 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:35 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 10 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 html
drwxrwxr-x.  2 admin admin 4096 Jan 27 09:00 logs
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 admin admin   11 Jan 23 11:21 www -> html/public

[admin@web01 ~]# ls -al /var/www/sites/example.com/html
drwxrwxr-x. 10 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 .
drwxrwxr-x.  4 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 11 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 application
drwxrwxr-x.  8 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 data
drwxrwxr-x.  3 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 docs
drwxrwxr-x.  3 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:22 library
drwxrwxr-x.  6 admin admin 4096 Jan 27 15:57 public
drwxrwxr-x.  3 admin admin 4096 Jan 24 09:33 scripts
drwxrwxr-x.  4 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 tests

[admin@web01 ~]# ls -al /var/www/sites/example.com/html/public
drwxrwxr-x.  6 admin admin 4096 Jan 27 15:57 .
drwxrwxr-x. 10 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  4 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 assets
drwxrwxr-x.  4 admin admin 4096 Jan 23 11:21 css
-rw-rw-r--.  1 admin admin   17 Jan 24 10:37 index.php
drwxrwxr-x.  4 admin admin 4096 Jan 24 09:33 js
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 admin admin    9 Jan 24 10:37 phpinfo.php -> index.php
```

## Error log

```
2014/01/24 10:37:52 [error] 8286#0: *15 FastCGI sent in stderr:
"Unable to open primary script: /var/www/sites/example.com/www/index.php
(No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream,
client: XXX, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.example.com"
```

---

## Update

1. Updated my config to include everything
2. Added permissions for /, /var, /var/www, etc
3. Turned off SELinux completely with no effect

---

## Update #2

Removed the `try_files` line from the `location ... .php$` line and edited php.ini's `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`. Realized I hadn't restarted php-fpm this whole time. **Magically working now!** If you can explain why phpinfo.php was working the whole time and index.php was not (even though they resided in the same directory, and phpinfo.php was a symlink to index.php!!) you get the bounty.

Comment: It could be because `include fastcgi_params` overrides `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME...`. what if you move `include fastcgi_params` just before the `fastcgi_pass` directive ?

Comment: @user2196728 Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, no effect.

Comment: My guess is your fastcgi server doesn't have the correct permissions for selinux.  Check selinux's audit log to see if it's blocking the file from the php executable.

Comment: @DerfK Nothing there. Not sure that would explain why phpinfo.php is working and index.php isn't either

Comment: What happens if you point the root directly to: /var/www/sites/example.com/html/public? Does this alter the behavior at all?

Comment: @JasonIlicic No change.

Comment: Hmm I tried your configuration and it works without any issues on my end, even with SELinux enforced. What happens if you remove your "index.php" file, and replace it with a new "index.php" with the contents of "<?php echo "This is a test"; ?>" (without the quotes)? Is it able to find the file?

Comment: It seems that FastCGI dont likes the symlinks for www->html/public. Could you test if it all works without them>

Comment: Can you also include the global nginx configuration?

Comment: @Andrei Mikhaltsov: There should be no issue with symlinks. I use them all the time with my Nginx/PHP-FPM configuration with versioned deployments. I'm curious to see if it works using a simple "Hello world" script...

Comment: @JasonIlicic I had tried changing index.php to the simplest "hello world" I could, but no change. Please see update

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your nginx.conf:

```
fastcgi_index index.php;
```

e.g. the relevant section of your nginx.conf file would look like this:

```
# Pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include       fastcgi.conf;
    try_files     $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

What this does is tell fastcgi to use index.php if a file is not specified.  For the record, I am using a patched nginx 1.2.9 (I changed ~* to ~ because that's how it looks in my nginx.conf)

Answer (score -1):

In nginx server block conf your root is root   `/var/www/sites/example.com/www`

Path to files is `/var/www/sites/example.com/html/public`

I know your phpinfo.php works, but try to make paths the same.

Also if phpinfo works, rename that phpinfo.php to index.php and see if it works.